# YouTube custom embed sizer

Tags: jquery, math, youtube, height, width

On a site I am building, I need to allow the video (iframe embed) to dynamically stretch to fit the screen. I will be grabbing the width of the parent div with jQuery, but I need to work out the math to automatically work out the height size.

YouTube has managed to do this in their custom sizer (click share, then embed and fill in the width to see the height automatically fill in).

Any ideas would be really useful, thanks!

---

**Edit**

Thanks to [Eray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556169/eray) for the help with this! If anyone is interested, here is the final working code (I think it works, anyway!):

```
$documentWidth = $('#wrap').width();
$theWidth = parseInt($documentWidth, 10);
$theHeight = (Math.floor($theWidth / 1.755) || 0) + 30;
$('#video iframe').height($theHeight);
$('#video iframe').width($documentWidth);
```

I am still not 100% sure how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get original **width/height** ratio . And then use this formula :

```
New Width = New Height * (Original Width/Original Height)
```

So you will keep same ratio on new width height combination.

Comment: I need to find the height, not width. Also, this gets a different result in the YouTube custom sizer (even when rounded).

Comment: `New Height = New Width / (Original Width/Original Height)` or in other words = `New Height = New Width / Ratio` ?

Comment: Ah! Thanks, but there is still something missing. With your math, 720 width gets 439 height but on YouTube I get (width/height) 720/440, 721/440, 722/441, 723/441, 724/442, 725/442, 726/443, 727/444, 728/444, 729/445. Any idea on how that works!

Comment: you right, using this script for calculation : http://pastebin.com/CRVQVXnj on 143th line it's adding 30px to height

Comment: Ah, nice and confusing, just the way I like it! Thanks :D

Comment: i can't help anymore sorry :))